# How do I fade out a background image in a gradient so that the elements beneath it are seen?

Tags: css

Let's say I have a `div` with a background image of a kitten. How can I fade out the the background image in a gradient pattern, without fading out the contents of the div?

I also want to make sure that whatever elements are beneath are seen through the fading out background image, I don't want it to just fade to white.

#### Example:

Here is some example HTML code, how would I fade out the background image of the element with the class `fade-out-background`?

```
<div style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jypCc.jpg')">
    <div class="fade-out-background" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCbFO.jpg')">
        This text should not fade out with the background image.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I what the end-result to look like:

[image: Desired result]

Resources: [link to kitten image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCbFO.jpg) and [link to pattern image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jypCc.jpg).

Comment: I haven't found a duplicate that matches all three of these criteria: the background image needs to fade out (not just a colour), the content of the element must not also fade out, and the elements underneath must be seen through it, not a solid colour like white.

Comment: Add your css to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Easiest way would be to just move your text to a copy div that lies on top of the first one and only fade out the first div.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with only CSS

Comment: I don't want to turn my question into a code snippet or add more CSS, I think the image I included is enough, and I want to keep irrelevant CSS out of the question.

Comment: Also, to clarify, this is not an animation, by "fade out" I mean the transparency increases from top to bottom, not with the passage of time.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible but it is hacky as hell:

html:

```
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body><div class="whole-page">
      <div class="content-area-bg1"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg2"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg3"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg4"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg5"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg6"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg7"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg8"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg9"></div>
      <div class="content-area-bg10"></div>
      <div class="content-area"><h1>This text should<br>not fade out with<br>the background<br>image</h1></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
:root{

  --textcolor-1: #fff;

  }

html{

  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

*{

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

*, *::before, *::after{

  box-sizing: inherit;

}

body {

background-image: url("../kittenbg.jpg");
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.6rem;
font-size: 1.25rem;
color: var(--textcolor-1);

}

.whole-page{

width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

.header{

height: 7rem;
text-align: center;

}

h1 {

  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 4.8rem;

}

.content-area-bg1
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 287px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg1::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;   
}

.content-area-bg2
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 260px;
  top: -287;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg2::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9;   
}

.content-area-bg3
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 230px;
  top: -547;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg3::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -8;   
}


.content-area-bg4
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -777;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg4::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -7;   
}

.content-area-bg5
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 170px;
  top: -977;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg5::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -6;   
}

.content-area-bg6
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 140px;
  top: -1147;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg6::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;   
}

.content-area-bg7
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 110px;
  top: -1287;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg7::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -4;   
}

.content-area-bg8
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 80px;
  top: -1397;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg8::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -3;   
}

.content-area-bg9
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -1477;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg9::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;   
}

.content-area-bg10
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -1527;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.content-area-bg10::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../kitten.jpg");
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}

.content-area
{

  width: 408px;
  height: 287px;
  top: -1547;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;

}
```

Comment: and the background is not a color ... read the question again

Comment: The question doesn't actually make sense, feel free to correct my interpretation though: he has an image in the background of a div that needs to fade out into whatever is the background that the div that has the background image that needs to fade out is placed on. This can work if the background is a solid colour that he matches the overlay gradient with and allow anything placed within the grid to sit atop and not fade.

Comment: @Edunikki I don't understand why the question doesn't make sense. I'm looking for a result like in the image. If it can't be done in CSS, that's OK, I would accept an answer saying it can't be done.